# FROM keyword not found where expected Error in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I've been working with our coder from another office over email, and we've hit a bit of a stand still with this code. I keep getting oracle errors whenever I try and execute the query. Below is the code I'm using:

```
SELECT TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.SHIFT_DT, TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.LOGON_ID, TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD,
   SUM(case TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD
         WHEN 'PUT' THEN TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY
         ELSE 0
       END) AS Puts,
   SUM(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY) AS SUM(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY)
FROM   WBR_RW.TALLY_TRAN_MSTR
GROUP BY TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.SHIFT_DT, TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.LOGON_ID
HAVING ((Puts/(SUM(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY))) > 0.75)
ORDER BY TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.SHIFT_DT, TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.LOGON_ID;
```

Is there anything that's wrong with this that might cause that error? Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Try change to Puts/Totals) without 'charaters

Comment: I don't see `CASE` inside the first `SUM()` function.  Isn't that needed?

Comment: @StevenK.Mariner When I did that, the error changed from MIssing Right Parenthesis to "TOTALS": invalid identifier.

Comment: In your HAVING, try replacing your 'Totals' with the entire `SUM(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY)`

Comment: @JacobH When I did that I got the error message "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: `SUM(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY) AS SUM(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY)` not valid alias

Comment: Sorry I meant in the having, not the column alias!

Answer (score 2):

Gonna leverage some sweet, sweet aliases here:

```
SELECT T.SHIFT_DT,
       T.LOGIN_ID,
       T.PRI_GRP_CD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.PRI_GRP_CD = 'PUT'
                THEN T.FULL_PLLT_QTY
                ELSE 0
           END) AS Puts,
       SUM(T.FULL_PLLT_QTY) AS SUM_PLLT_QTY
FROM WBR_RW.TALLY_TRAN_MSTR AS T
GROUP BY T.SHIFT_DT, T.LOGON_ID, T.PRI_GRP_CD
HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN T.PRI_GRP_CD = 'PUT'
                THEN T.FULL_PLLT_QTY
                ELSE 0
           END) / SUM(T.FULL_PLLT_QTY)) > .75
ORDER BY T.SHIFT_DT, T.LOGON_ID;
```

See how that works for you.  Changes are the last column alias and the `HAVING` clause being explicit.